# csv file generated with Perl broken

Tags: excel, perl, csv, export-to-csv

I created a `csv` file using the perl module `Text::CSV_XS`.
Here is the relevant code:

```
open (my $csv_fh, '>', $tmp_file) or die("Unable to open CSV '$tmp_file' for write");

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({'binary' => 1, 'sep_char' => $config->{'csv'}->{'sep_char'}, 'eol' => "\015\012"}) or die(Text::CSV->error_diag());

$csv->print($csv_fh, ["ID", "ASEITE", "ERDAT", "QUELLE", "AUSGABE", "RESSORT", "AUTNR", "NAME", "ANZHLZEIL", "ANZHLZEICH", "UEBER", "TEXTSP", "ART", "BETRAG", "GRUND", "FEST", "STATUS", "SLEVEL"]);

$csv->print($csv_fh, ["A","1","AB","A-5","01","12345","12345","NAME","0","0","Testtext","Testtext2","1","45","","","0",""]);

close $csv_fh;
```

When i try to open the [file](https://cloud.gmx.net/ngcloud/external?locale=de&guestToken=FezSfjMERX2QA2Av9pppVg&loginName=Ovaron20@gmx.net#_) using Microsoft Excel i get the message that the filename extension (csv) does not match the format/structure of the file.
I get asked if i trusted the source. After klicking 'ok' i receive the information that there was an error. Again i click 'ok'. After that i can see the csv headline plus the only line of the file. Everything looks as expected.

My question: **Why do i get this error message opening the file? What is wrong with the file i created?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open a text file whose first 2 characters are "ID" in Excel, it thinks it's a SYLK file, and so gives this warning. This is a very old issue with Excel. See [this Microsoft Support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323626) for example. The error will go away if you put quotes around `ID` or change its case.